# How to Export access table as excel file in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, excel, oledb

I have search all over internet but can't find the way to export an access table as Excel file in vb.net

Comment: Can you get the Access table into a `DataTable` ? That would be a good place to start.

Comment: Your search skills need work: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6854750/1070452 among 70,000 others

Comment: This one too. It's C# but it's very handy - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20496952/programmatically-export-query-table-from-ms-access-to-excel-using-c-sharp

Comment: You could create a DataAdapter, setup a SQL INSERT statement with parameters coupled with a SQL SELECT statement. Load data from msaccess via the adapter then loop through the underlying data table and perform inserts. I have a working conceptual example on Microsoft One Drive to see what I am talking about https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=A3D5A9A9A28080D1!887&authkey=!AFT5GkDGDcUT7uI&ithint=file%2czip